# Game transitions rapidly between states with no apparent cause

Tags: unity, c#

I am working on an idle game for my portfolio (or release it if it's good enough). It consists of a few modules at the time of this post: Exploration, Anomaly, Encounter, and Combat. Each of these modules flows into each other automatically.

I am having an issue where it would rapidly go from Exploration to Encounter without any code telling it to do so. It's also flipping from Exploration to Anomaly sporadically without my consent. I am unsure of what is wrong here. I shall present some code samples for context

Exploration code:

```
    public IEnumerator Exploration()
    {
        ProcessVisualizer.ResetRotation = true;
        IsExploring = true;
        GameObject.Find("Process Visualizer").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        GameObject.Find("Process Visualizer").GetComponent<ProcessVisualizer>().enabled = true;
        GameObject.Find("Status").GetComponent<Text>().text = "STATUS: EXPLORE";
        GameObject.Find("Status").GetComponent<Text>().color = new Color(0, 244, 0);

        int BombExplodeChance = Random.Range(0, 1000000); // Go do a lottery if he explodes.
        int AnomalyChance = Random.Range(5, 20);
        int AnomalyChanceHit = Random.Range(5, 20);
        
        string[] ExploreText = { "Redacted text array here." };
        
        H.text = ExploreText[Random.Range(0, ExploreText.Length)];
        H.fontSize = (int)(.1 * Screen.height);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(5,10));
        
        if(AnomalyChance == AnomalyChanceHit && IsExploring == true)
        {
            IsExploring = false;
            StartCoroutine(AnomalyInvestigate()); // Something interesting in the horizon.
        }
        if(AnomalyChance == BombExplodeChance)
        {
            H.text = NameOfPlayer + "'s bomb hums so loud with excitement that it blew up the ship, killing " + NameOfPlayer + ".";
            GameObject.Find("Status").GetComponent<Text>().text = "STATUS: DEAD (BOMB)";
            GameObject.Find("Status").GetComponent<Text>().color = new Color(255, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            IsExploring = false;
            StartCoroutine(Exploration());
        }
    }
```

Anomaly code:

```
    public IEnumerator AnomalyInvestigate()
    {
        ProcessVisualizer.ResetRotation = true;
        IsInvestigating = true;
        GameObject.Find("Process Visualizer").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        GameObject.Find("Process Visualizer").GetComponent<ProcessVisualizer>().enabled = true;
        GameObject.Find("Status").GetComponent<Text>().text = "STATUS: ANOMALY";
        GameObject.Find("Status").GetComponent<Text>().color = Color.yellow;
        string[] InvestigationBanter = { "Redacted Anomaly Text Array" };
        int EventChance = Random.Range(5, 20);
        int ContactChance = Random.Range(5, 20);
        int BombExplodeChance = Random.Range(0, 1000000); // Go do a lottery if he explodes.

        H.text = InvestigationBanter[Random.Range(0, InvestigationBanter.Length)];
        H.fontSize = (int)(.1 * Screen.height);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(5, 20));

        if(EventChance > ContactChance && IsInvestigating == true)
        {
            IsInvestigating = false;
            StartCoroutine(Encounter());
        }
        if(EventChance < ContactChance && IsInvestigating == true)
        {
            IsInvestigating = false;
            StartCoroutine(Exploration());
        }
        if (EventChance == BombExplodeChance)
        {
            H.text = NameOfPlayer + "'s bomb hums so loud with interest that it blew up the ship, killing " + NameOfPlayer + ".";
            GameObject.Find("Status").GetComponent<Text>().text = "STATUS: DEAD (BOMB)";
            GameObject.Find("Status").GetComponent<Text>().color = new Color(255, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            IsInvestigating = false;
            StartCoroutine(AnomalyInvestigate());
        }
        
    }
```

Exploration is supposed to be the majority of the game, but it's flipping between that an anomaly as well as encounter (which is similar to anomaly). The process visualizer gives the player something else to look at if they get bored with the text.

To conclude my cry for help, I haven't been able to identify the problem. Some suggestions would be nice.

Comment: There are a lot of coroutines here. Any chance that some of them run simultaneously when they aren't supposed to?

Comment: For some reason, they do seem to be running simultaneously. I'm just unsure of what's causing it. When I added a breakpoint to the first statement in exploration, it seems to go into the anomaly routine without changing the status text until it reaches Anomaly's first if statment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having code which heavily relies on coroutines can get pretty messy. It gets very hard to stay aware of which coroutines are active at the same time and how they interact with each other. But what I think what might be going on here is the following.

First this gets executed

```
if(EventChance > ContactChance && IsInvestigating == true)
{
    IsInvestigating = false;
    StartCoroutine(Encounter());
}
```

What happens here is that the coroutine `Encounter` is started. But that does not mean that this function we are currently in gets aborted. No, it keeps executing and comes to this part:

```
else
{
    IsInvestigating = false;
    StartCoroutine(AnomalyInvestigate());
}
```

What happens here is that a second `AnomalyInvestigate` coroutine gets started.

Now we have two coroutines running at the same time: `Encounter` and `AnomalyInvestigate`. Both use a very long pause for 5 to 20 seconds before doing something, so first one does something and then a couple seconds later the other does something.

---

So... How do we fix that?

If your intention is to abort the current coroutine and start a new one, then immediately leave the current coroutine with `return;` after scheduling the next one. That way the current coroutine will abort after scheduling the new one and won't execute any of its following code:

```
StartCoroutine(Encounter());
return;
```

But honestly, I think you should seriously overthink your software architecture. I am not seeing the full picture here, but one architectural pattern which seems to be appropriate to me here is the [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). A state machine means that there are multiple states your game can be in, and when that state notices that some condition is true, it leaves to a different state.

An elegant way to do this in Unity is to implement every state with an own game object. But only one of these objects is active at the same time - the one for the state the game is currently in. Each state has a separate MonoBehaviour controlling what happens during that state. The `Update` method of these scripts are a good place to check if a condition is fulfilled which requires to switch to a different state. When that's the case, the object activates the corresponding object and deactivates itself.

But keep in mind that even when an object deactivates itself with `gameObject.SetActive(false);`, it will run the current method to the end. So you still should follow it with `return;`. The code you want to run at the beginning of switching to each state can be implemented in [`OnEnable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html). You can also use [`OnDisable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html) for any cleanup code which is supposed to be run when the state is left.

The state objects also can have sub-objects which include things which are only supposed to be in the game while the game is in that state. Like a canvas with state-specific UI, for example.

Oh, and by the way, these states can also have coroutines. When an object gets deactivated, then any coroutines it is currently running also get stopped. So if you insist on using a coroutine to handle the internal logic of some states, you are free to do that.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I shall do a state machine once I get this prototype up and off the ground. With my experience with programming, I tend to misunderstand the use of `return` which causes things to be messy. Again, thanks for your kind answer.